# How to keep the windows casting ( WinKey + K) always open in the background so whenever i am using my tablet - I can connect right from the tablet

Tags: casting, screen, display, sharing, split-screen

So currently I have to press (Win+K) keys to open the casting window and then it finds my tablet (where i select the second screen option) and both connect this way.

I would like the windows part to be automatic - always on - so whenever i have the tablet - and press the second screen option - it automatically connects to the windows.

So i don't have to go and press Win+K keys on windows pc.

Seemingly sounds like i should have to turn some switch on in windows but there isn't one and nobody seems to have talked about it.

I've already scoured the internet and couldn't find any help regarding this. Think there might be some hidden setting or registry that might need to be tweeked.

Also I've only connected my tablet so I do not want any other people's tablets to connect to my windows as well... (like it should remember my tablet)